# bash script to copy specific set of files

Tags: bash

I have a set of files named by numbers from 1 to 1000 .csv, I want to copy files whose name starts with 1 with 2 or less digits(eg. 1,10,11,12,etc).
how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily :

```
cp 1[0-9].csv /home
cp 1.csv /home
```

Save this as *file.sh*
and then run as

```
$bash file.sh
```

This will copy all files to home Directory

Comment: Hah, of course :D Much better than both my answers! I'm leaving it in place because someone might learn something from them :)

Comment: Yes! Your answer contains much more information to learn & use Regex
:)

Comment: This will fail to copy `1.csv` but that is easy to fix, of course.

Comment: I don't see why you would need to save the command to a file, unless you know you will need to repeat it often. It works just fine from the command line, too, obviously.

Comment: @tripleee: Thanks for the fix. 
Now you can see what is the point of saving it in the file.
And ofcouse you do it the normal way.

Comment: Actually `cp 1.csv 1[0-9].csv /home` (as in @Thomas' answer) is how I would have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way that should always work:

```
find -regex '\./1[0-9]?\.csv' -exec cp {} destination \;
```

As `find` uses the full path, we have to match a `./` at the beginning. Then follows a literal `1`, then optionally (note the `?`) a character from the range `0-9`, and finally the extension. Any `.`s must be escaped as `\.`.

For each matching file, `find` will execute the command given by `-exec`, up to the `\;`, substituting `{}` by the filename.

To check that it catches the right files, do just:

```
find -regex '\./1[0-9]?\.csv'
```

---

A simpler way, that works if there's no other clutter in your directory:

```
cp 1.csv 1?.csv destination
```